# In Angular8 I got some issue in routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I installed Angular 8 and also installed Universal for SEO purpose, all parts are done and my Angular 8 application successfully run. Then I create a new component the name of the component is `student`, then I go to `app-routing.modules.ts` file and include:

`const routes: Routes = [{path:'/student', component:StudentComponent},];`

Then I run my app and navigate to url http://localhost:4000/student and following error occurs:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student'at router_ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (D:\Angular\mydemo\dist\server\main.js:117488:16)`

Please help me out I tried many times to resolve it but the issue is still same.

Comment: Could you please share the content of `app-routing.module.ts` and the content of `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Can you show your's **app-routing.modules.ts**?

Comment: remove the slash before `student`

Comment: aap.module.ts:  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: 'students',
      component: StudentComponent
    }
  
  ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StudentComponent
  ],

Comment: app-routing.module.ts:-import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component';


const routes: Routes = [
{path:'student', component:StudentComponent},


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { 


}

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `app-routing.modules.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [{path:'student', component:StudentComponent},];
```

Comment: Please remove  const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'students', component: StudentComponent } ]; from app.module.ts

Comment: and add imports: [
    AppRoutingModule], in app.module.ts